# Missing compiler warnings in templated library code

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-warnings

The following code emits a (correct) warning with clang 3.9:

```
#include <warning_global_symlink.hpp>
#include "warning_local_symlink.hpp"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{   
    // This line shows no warning whatsoever.     
    WarningGlobalSymlink< int > symlink;

    // This line correctly shows the warning
    WarningLocalSymlink< int > local;
}
```

Every *_symlink.hpp is a symlink pointing to a header with the following content:

```
#pragma once

template < typename T >
class Warning*Symlink
{
  public:
    Warning*Symlink()
    {
        init();
    }

    bool init()
    {
        // I will trigger a warning because of missing return!
    }
};
```

Interestingly the global symlinked header doesn't show the warning. The global class is in another cmake project that gets compiled as dependency.

Is there a possibility to show warnings in globally symlinked headers?

Note:

1) If the global headers get copied instead of symlinked, everything works as espected.

2) With the locally symlinked header everything works as espected, too.

Comment: Do both files contain the correct `*`? E.g. did you use `WarningGlobalSymlink` in `WarningGlobalSymlink`?

Comment: Yes, but other than that, it is the same code.

Comment: It's point 1) (it has to be a symlink rather than a copy), which boggles me!  I wonder if there is some sort of heuristic that symlinked `<>` headers are "library" headers, and you don't want warnings about library headers?

Comment: Ooh.  In particular, if the preprocessor has found file /foo/bar/GlobalSymlink.h, it can see that it is definitely not a system library header, and so issue warnings.  If it has found a symlink, it may not bother tracking where there symlink is going to, and just suppress warnings in that file.

Comment: @MartinBonner: But the local symlink emits a warning! As far as I know we don't surpress warnings (e.g. via compiler flags) for external libraries other than in the associated cmake file for external projects.

Comment: Local symlink - the heurist may be that "" includes are not treated as system includes.  Suppressing compiler warnings for system header files may be the default.

Comment: Yes: from http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers "Warnings are suppressed when they occur in system headers." - but there is nothing about symlinks there.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Removing them using --no-system-header-prefix=... triggers all warnings correctly. Thank you!